# Find the limit of $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(2b_n+\frac{5}{b_n^2})$

Tags: calculus

> Find the limit of $$b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(2b_n+\frac{5}{b_n^2})$$
>
> Using AM-MG inequity, Where $b_1>0$

I can show that the limit is $\sqrt[3]{5}$ by solving

$$L=\frac{1}{3}(2L+\frac{5}{L^2})$$

Then I will need to show that it is monotonic increasing/decreasing, but how can AM-MG can be used here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit $ a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(2a_n + \frac{5}{a_n^{2}}), a_1 > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007963/limit-a-n1-frac132a-n-frac5a-n2-a-1-0)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x_1=b_n,x_2=b_n,x_3=5/b_n^2$. The AM-GM inequality tells us that

$${x_1+x_2+x_3\over 3}\geq \sqrt[3]{x_1x_2x_3}$$

The LHS is $b_{n+1}$ and the RHS is $\sqrt[3]{5}$. So $b_{n+1}\geq \sqrt[3]{5}$

To prove the sequence is decreasing it suffices to note that

$$b_{n+1}-b_n={5-b_n^2\over 3b_n^2}$$

This proof can be generalised to

$${1\over k}\left((k-1)a_n+{b\over a_n^{k-1}}\right)\to \sqrt[k]{b}$$